# Single ALB ingress with multiple services, need to set different health check paths for different services

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

I have a single ALB deployed as an ingress controller running around 10 services. In the target group I want to set the health check path differently for each service. How do I do it?

I tried setting it like this-

```
"alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-group-attributes" = "frontend-auth_healthcheck_path=/auth/abcd|frontend-leads_healthcheck_path=/leads/abcd|email-marketing_list_healthcheck_path=/list/abcd"
```

Got this error-

```
Warning  FailedDeployModel  11m  ingress  Failed deploy model due to ValidationError: 1 validation error detected: Value 'frontend-auth_healthcheck-path' at 'attributes.1.member.key' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: ^[a-zA-Z0-9._]+$
           status code: 400, request id: e4d21447-6028-4298-ab4c-30e6e91fbe53
```

Then I tried this-

```
"alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-group-attributes" = "frontend_auth_healthcheck_path=/auth/abcd|frontend_leads_healthcheck_path=/leads/abcd|email_marketing_list_healthcheck_path=/list/abcd"
```

Got this error-

```
Warning  FailedDeployModel  2m28s  ingress  Failed deploy model due to ValidationError: Target group attribute key 'frontend_auth_healthcheck_path' is not recognized
           status code: 400, request id: aa6b55cb-e931-4ddc-8933-7dbdceb45063
```